# WPF - SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the `SaveFileDialog` in WPF to export into an excel file at a particular location selected by the user. But in between when `SaveFileDailog` is opened and the user clicks on `Cancel button` on dialog, I am getting another dialog that says `"Do you want to save changes you made to 'Sheet1'?"` and then `"Export completed"` instead of cancelling the export.

So what do I have to do to tackle it? Anything in WPF, something like `'DialogResult'` that is the same as in winForms?

Answer (score 53):

SaveFileDialog will return true if user saved (the `ShowDialog` method returns a nullable bool), and return false/null if user pressed cancel. Below is a sample [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx) code to get you started:

```
// Configure save file dialog box
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show save file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process save file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make use of MessageBox in WPF to open another window when users click cancel. Add the following code to the cancel button event :-

```
private void canceButton()
    {
        MessageBoxResult key = MessageBox.Show(
            "Are you sure you want to quit",
            "Confirm",
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
            MessageBoxImage.Question,
            MessageBoxResult.No);
        if (key == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [DialogResult Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) for using a dialog result in WPF. For more information on using dialogresult in WPF refer to [WPF Dialogs and DialogResult](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/wpf-dialogs-and-dialogresult/)

Answer (score 0):

It will Perform as you want on cancel and ok Button of SaveFileDialog

```
bool? DialougeResult = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if(DialougeResult)
    {
    // your code now its cancel when click cancel button 
    }
```